# How to change the default string length in mysql?

Tags: mysql

so I am importing a database file to mysql and I got  Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes,
I want to do something similar to :
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
but directly in mysql because I am not inserting the data from laravel but doing it directly.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix ?